# Overriding delete operator for base and derived class in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

Below is my sample code, where I overrided the delete operator for derived class.

My aim is I want to delete the object for both base and derived class in delete operator. Basically I want to hold the address of both class till delete operator get called.

Right now I am using atomic operation to synchronize, basically my destructor didn't get called, when I am executing some functionality of class. Now, I want to get ride of that atomic operation. So, I will catch the object address and hold there in delete operator till it is safe to do. Destructor will be called by others.

So, which is the correct place for delete operator, base class or derived class? When I used delete operator in both class only derived delete operator get called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
     int l;
     base() {cout << " base const" << endl;}
     ~base() { cout << " base descr" << endl;}
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
 int k;
 derived() {cout << " derived const" << endl;}
 ~derived() { cout << " derived descr" << endl;}
 static void operator delete (void *p) {
      return delete[] static_cast<char*>(p);
  }

};

int main () {
  derived *p = new derived;
  p->k = 7;
  p->l = 8;
  cout << p <<" " << p->k << " " <<p->l << endl;
  delete p
}
```

Comment: Don not do that(!) - overload the whole package of new/delete (although, you might do it here and forward to ::delete, for debugging purposes, but match delete without [] and delete with [])

Comment: What on earth are you doing!

Comment: @Cyber: Not really...

Comment: Well besides all the undefined behavior regarding that `delete` operation of course

Comment: @DieterLücking can you gave me reason for overriding both new and delete

Comment: Please describe the purpose of the overridden `delete` operator more precisely.

Comment: @eswaat You usually don't _"Overriding delete operator"_, that's for very special use cases only, that you're not meeting as far I can see from your quesiton.

Comment: @Codor I edited the question, I hope it will be clear.

Comment: @eswaat Your recent edit at least qualifies, you're not matching a valid use case for _overriding `new` and `delete`_ of these classes . _"Basically I want to hold the address of both class"_ It boils down to the same address actually.